# Select row depending on what is linked to it in other table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have just two tables. The first is "Objects" and the second is "Properties". Now I want objects with specified properties.

Objects Table:

```
+-----------+
| Column    |
+-----------+
| object_id |
+-----------+
```

Properties Table:

```
+-------------+
| Columns     |
+-------------+
| property_id |
| object_id   |
| key         |
| value       |
+-------------+
```

Now what I wanne select is of course all objects by predicates (AND, OR, XOR).

e.g.:

```
property_id object_id key      value
 1           2         name     Mike
 2           2         gender   male
 3           2         hair     blonde
 4           2         married  yes
 5           5         name     John
 6           5         gender   male
 7           5         married  yes
 8           5         job      Cop
```

Say I want to select all objects with the gender="male" and married="yes".

Do you have any idea, how this is achieved most efficient with MySQL? And is it clear enough what I need?

Chrispi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly it is something like

```
 Select object_id 
 from objects
 where object_id in (select object_id from properties where gender="male") and 
       object_id in (select object_id from properties where married="yes") ;
```

An alternative using only properties:

```
(select object_id from properties where gender="male") 
 intersect
(select object_id from properties where married="yes");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Unfortunately INTERSECT is not available in MySQL, but your first snippet did it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use  a self join and better to index columns that appear in where and joining clause

```
select t.* from 
test t
join test t1 using(object_id) /* using is short syntax for join you also use on(t.object_id = t1.object_id) */
where t.`key` = 'gender'
and t1.`key` = 'married'
and t.`value` = 'male'
and t1.`value` = 'yes'
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc29f9/2)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following statement you can get the results.

```
(Select object_id from Properties where key = 'married' and value = 'yes')
intersect
(Select object_id from Properties where key = 'gender' and value = 'male')
```

Also based on your criteria, you can add more conditions in above.

Comment: I think it is "intersect" instead of "intersects"

Comment: But INTERSECT unfortunately is not for MySQL, it's SQL only.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done efficiently in a RDBMS. However, you can achieve it along the lines of:

```
SELECT object_id FROM your_table t1 
INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON (
    t1.object_id = t2.object_id 
    AND t2.property_id = 4 
    AND t2.value = 'yes')
WHERE t1.property_id = 6 and t1.value = 'male';
```

Comment: I'm aware that OODBMS would be appropriate. Sometimes you have to take what you can get. ;)